# Choosing spec feature file in wdio at runtime

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I want to run different feature files based and want to decide it at runtime, i.e via command line arguments.

Everytime I uncomment the file and then run the test. 
Tried working with cucumber tags and did not get around it.

specs: [

```
//   'features/subscription/create.feature'
// './features/payment/create.feature'
```

],

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the command you are using to run your tests? I usually say stay away from absolute paths when running tests and instead use tags. You said tags are not working but you don't say why

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways as far as i know:

1. Defining `suites` with required feature files and pass the suite name as parameter to WDIO test.

Detailed explanation on suites: https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites.html
NOTE: In case if you are using `npm test` for starting the test, then use `npm test -- --suite login` to pick a suite.(this is not mentioned in the file).

2. You can directly pass in the features through command line as like below:

In you `wdio.conf.js` file write the below lines above the `exports.config` and parameter the `spec` value.

```
var features = process.env.FEATURE || './features/**/*.feature';
var featureArray = features.split(',');
exports.config = { .... spec: featureArray, ....} //skipped others
```

now while triggering the test use the command like below:
`FEATURE='./features/test.feature,./features/test1.feature' npm test`

So when the execution begins, `features` will receive the string and we converted that to array and passing as parameter to `spec`.

Hope this helps.